# Javascript contains django tags

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

```
<script>

 //Handle the callback on success

 function stateChange(){

    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200) {

    //request is successful. So retrieve the values in the response
    var display_language = xmlHttp.responseText.split(';');
    alert("response: " + display_language);

    var newHtml = '{% for chunk in video.chunks.all %} {% for c in chunk.chunklets.all%} <tr> <td>{{c.start}}</td> <td> {% spaceless %} {%for item in c.contents.all%}{%if item.lang ==  display_language %}{{item.text.strip}}{%endif%}{%endfor%} {% endspaceless %} </td> <td>{{c.finish}}</td> </tr> {%endfor%} {%endfor%}';

    $('#xxx').html(newHtml);
    }
}
</script>
```

If I use the above code, the display_language value is null. But alert can print the value of display_language. Just the display_language can not be passed into newHtml.

If it is changed to

```
var newHtml = '{% for chunk in video.chunks.all %} {% for c in chunk.chunklets.all%} <tr> <td>{{c.start}}</td> <td> {% spaceless %} {%for item in c.contents.all%}{%if item.lang ==';

newHtml +=  display_language +'%}{{item.text.strip}}{%endif%}{%endfor%} {% endspaceless %} </td> <td>{{c.finish}}</td> </tr> {%endfor%} {%endfor%}';
```

The error is that ""Invalid block tag: 'endif', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to mix Javascript and Django templates too much. Remember that all of the Django is run first, and then all of the javascript will be run. So because the `display_language` value is created in Javascript, you can't use it in your Django template. I would recommend just passing all of your data into Javascript, and then constructing your newHtml value in pure javascript.